# Pleasure in Shower

Tags: the-buddha, traditions, tipitaka, personal-experience

Q:

I follow Yuttadhammo's tradition and I wanted to know how to prevent the pleasure I get in taking showers. Everytime I take them, I have a clinging to the warmth of the water and the feeling of it.

> How do I prevent this or come to disattach from the experiences I
>   have in showering and getting pleasure from it?

Answer (score 1):

The idea isn't to prevent pleasure nessasarily.

The only way  that you can really go, is to be mindful of the pleasure and the other experiences that arise and fall in your field of attention as they are occurring. That is the way to detach from what is being clung to. If you're asking yourself "how can I prevent or detach from X then that is another thing that can be clung to.

However you also can investigate on an intellectual level. With the previous experience of being mindful it is more than your usual intellectual endeavor. While being mindful(ideally) You can ask things like:

Why do I cling to the pleasure?

What is the pleasure?

What is it that clings to the pleasure?

What triggered the clinging?

Also, you might want to set a time limit for the shower that would set boundaries and help balance consentration.

Answer (score 0):

We have an on-demand water heater. That is essentially the infinite hot shower. At some point one realizes that too much of anything is undesirable and one turns off the shower.

Therefore the point to consider is *when* to turn off the shower, not how to dis-attach from shower craving. If one is always mindful of personal, societal and environmental considerations, then one sees the hand moving automatically to turn off the shower.

For example, since I don't eat after lunch, sometimes I am careless in clothing and get quite chilled. So I take a warm shower and resolve to be more careful in keeping my body warm by staying properly clothed. And in taking that warm shower, I apologize to those whom I have deprived of water and electricity and gas for my lack of mindfulness, offering gratitude and a resolve to be more skillful.

Answer (score 0):

you may be under dressed, insufficiently warm all the times you're not in a comfortable hot shower. Wear more layers, keep your body warm, do enough cardiovascular and other physical exercises everyday (at least 30min)  to improve your base body temperature and overall physical health. Then when you step in a hot shower, it won't feel like anything especially comfortable. When your reserve energy is strong, you feel like you could eat or not eat, sleep or not sleep, get a massage or a hot shower and it will just feel neutral, nothing special. But if you lack nutrients, you will be ravenously hungry, you lack body heat, hot showers will feel great, if you lack good circulation, a massage and hot shower will feel great, etc.

On the mental cultivation side of things, develop kusala habits to replace akusala habits. Before I take a shower, I resolve to not waste water, get in and out quickly just to get the job done. Probably that's less than 1 minute of water running, 3-4 minutes of rubbing, drying, etc. Also, there's no need to lather a thick layer of soap everywhere on the body, or even a thin layer. You just need to make sure to use enough soap on the areas that actually need it, and this way you don't dry out your skin and nutrients in the skin. Once you form good habits, it just becomes automatic and you don't even have to think or fight temptation. And if you take care of the physical health aspect as described above, your health will be robust enough where you don't even feel temptation of the pleasure of hot showers.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I prevent this or come to disattach from the experiences Ihave in showering and getting pleasure from it?

Try to note the different experiences when taking a shower. Note the warm water as "warm, warm, warm" and if any liking arises, change object and note the liking as "liking, liking, liking". Keep noting it until it goes away. If it doesn't go away after a long time you can change the object back to rising and falling of the abdomen or any other object that arises, e.g. the sound of water or the feeling of feet touching the ground.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important thing is to stay mindful, and not become distracted by the sensations of a warm shower. The purpose of a shower is to clean my body: Once my body is clean, I get out of the shower.

On most days, I find it helpful to set the shower to the lowest comfortable temperature. The goal is to maintain a neutral sense of temperature, setting the water neither too hot nor too cold. This tends to make it easier to avoid the distraction.

Also, don't worry too much if you feel yourself being drawn to the warmth, as it is only natural. Just acknowledge it, watch it fall dissolve, and continue on your way.

From the Satipatthana Sutta:

> And further, monks, a monk lives contemplating mental objects of the five aggregates of clinging.
>
> How, monks, does a monk live contemplating mental objects of the five aggregates of clinging?
>
> ...Thus is feeling; thus is the arising of feeling; and thus is the disappearance of feeling...
>
> Thus he lives contemplating mental objects internally, or he lives contemplating mental objects externally, or he lives contemplating mental objects internally and externally. He lives contemplating origination factors in mental objects, or he lives contemplating dissolution factors in mental objects, or he lives contemplating origination-and-dissolution factors in mental objects. Or his mindfulness is established with the thought, "Mental objects exist," to the extent necessary just for knowledge and mindfulness, and he lives detached, and clings to nothing in the world. Thus also, monks, a monk lives contemplating mental objects in the mental objects of the five aggregates of clinging.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to, you may want to consider bathing with a bucket and glass. It uses a lot less water and is a much simpler approach. Try to make your necessities into luxuries.